# Python, include non-python files in a pathed directory in setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

My module in python requires 2-3 txt files. Unfortunately setup.py does not seem to be generating non-python files in the egg folder.

I tried this solution found online:

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup

setup(

    ...
    package_data={'': ['folder1/folder2/links.txt']},

}
```

But it promptly does not work. links.txt is nowhere to be found in the egg folder.

Any clues?

Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) may help

Comment: In addition, you need to add them to your `MANIFEST`

Comment: aser, it worked. however now my program does not have permissions to access blehh. I guess I need to change r+ to r ... But will there be a difference?